# Tetrahedralization visualization Octave

Tags: octave, delaunay

Hi does anyone know how to visualize the tetrahedrons in the output of the `delaunay3()` function in Octave?

http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html3/octave_151.html

In MATLAB this visualization is done with the `tetramesh()` function but Octave does not have this function built in!

The link does mention the `triplot` and `trimesh` functions but they only create triangles, not tetrahedra.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about this to give any thoughts on it. But, I would like to mention the following, in case you hadn't seen it before. There have been [discussions on tetramesh before](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/tetramesh-alternative-td2279685.html). A quick solution was written up by `martin_helm`:

```
function tetramesh( T, X, C)
  if nargin < 3
     C = mod((1:size(T, 1))'-1, size(colormap(), 1) + 1);
  endif
  triang = [T(:, 1) T(:, 2) T(:, 3); ...
            T(:, 2) T(:, 3) T(:, 4); ...
            T(:, 3) T(:, 4) T(:, 1); ...
            T(:, 4) T(:, 1) T(:, 2)];
  patch("Faces", triang, "Vertices", X, "FaceVertexCData", [C; C; C; C])
endfunction
```

Along with some example usage:

```
backend("fltk") % backend("gnuplot") could also be used
d = [-1 1];
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(d,d,d);
x = [x(:);0];
y = [y(:);0];
z = [z(:);0];

tetra = delaunay3(x,y,z);
X = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
tetramesh(tetra, X)
view(30,30)
```